# How can I know the minimum android version required by my Cordova project

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am working on a **Cordova** based project based on **Android**, and I am trying to know what is the **minimum version supported** by the Android platform.

I know it may depend most of the plugins I installed, but there are a lot of them and I think it is not very viable to review one by one to see the minimum version of them.

Is there any **tool or command** to know this?

PS: I know version **5.1.1** does not work but version **7+** works fine.

Here I leave a list of plugins that I had install:

- cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release 3.0.0 "cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release"
- cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release 3.0.0 "cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release"
- cordova-android-support-gradle-release 1.4.4 "cordova-android-support-gradle-release"
- cordova-plugin-android-permissions 1.0.0 "Permissions"
- cordova-plugin-app-launcher 0.4.0 "Launcher"
- cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.9 "AppVersion"
- cordova-plugin-audio-recorder 1.0.5 "Cordova Audio Recorder Plugin"
- cordova-plugin-auth-handler 1.0.1 "AuthHandler"
- cordova-plugin-badge 0.8.7 "Badge"
- cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.1 "Camera"
- cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
- cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
- cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.1 "Notification"
- cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1 "File"
- cordova-plugin-file-opener2 2.0.19 "File Opener2"
- cordova-plugin-firebase 2.0.5 "Google Firebase Plugin"
- cordova-plugin-firebase-crashlytics 0.0.6 "Cordova Firebase Crashlytics Plugin"
- cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.4.3 "Geolocation"
- cordova-plugin-hockeyapp 5.1.2 "HockeyApp"
- cordova-plugin-indexedDB 0.1.2 "IndexedDB polyfill"
- cordova-plugin-local-notification 0.9.0-beta.2 "LocalNotification"
- cordova-plugin-media 5.0.2 "Media"
- cordova-plugin-media-capture 3.0.2 "Capture"
- cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.1 "Network Information"
- cordova-plugin-photokandy-video-thumbnail 2.1.0 "Video Thumbnail"
- cordova-plugin-root-detection 0.1.1 "Root Detection"
- cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
- cordova-plugin-sslcertificatechecker 6.0.0 "SSL Certificate Checker"
- cordova-plugin-vibration 3.1.0 "Vibration"
- cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
- cordova-sqlite-storage 3.2.0 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin - cordova-sqlite-storage plugin version"
- kapsel-plugin-authproxy 3.15.0 "AuthProxy"
- kapsel-plugin-corelibs 3.15.0 "CoreLibs"
- kapsel-plugin-i18n 3.15.0 "i18n"
- kapsel-plugin-inappbrowser 3.15.0 "InAppBrowser"
- kapsel-plugin-logon 3.15.0 "Logon"
- kapsel-plugin-odata 3.15.0 "OData"
- kapsel-plugin-ui5 3.15.0 "ui5"
- onesignal-cordova-plugin 2.4.3 "OneSignal Push Notifications"
- phonegap-nfc 0.7.3 "NFC"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing this backwards.  You don't write an app then figure out the minimum version.  You pick the minimum version you want to support, based on marketshare and demographics of the different versions, and the effort it would take to support lower versions, and if there's any must have functionality that requires a specific version.  Then you pick only plugins that work for that version.  You don't create an app then try and figure out a minimum version-  doing it that way you have no idea if it supports the market you're aiming for.

Comment: I understand your point but I am not the only developer of this app and it seems that no one has placed "version limit" so we can work with that limit and this problem should not happen, but we didn't do it that way. So... Is there any way to know what I am asking? Thanks

Comment: Go through your dependencies one by one.  And then set that as the minimum version for the future and require people adding new plugins to ensure it doesn't change it.  Or just start with the version you know works and binary search looking for the lowest version which will build and not crash

Comment: I will try that, if I had no other answer with any tool or something I will mark you as the correct one. I appreciate your information, thanks